# Collapse-all in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-7

How do i collapse-all in NetBeans?

right-clicking one of the +/- tabs isn't doing it as it does in Eclipse.

so, im looking to collapse all the comments, or all the members, or everything while i'm viewing the code.

just looking to see how to toggle back&forth this in the editor.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either one of following:

- View->Code Folds->Collapse All
- Ctrl+Shift+Minus
- most files also have this in context menu: right click in editor->Code Folds->Collapse All